# Monotone Sequence Limit Question

Tags: analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a monotone increasing sequence that converges to a finite limit. If a monotone subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ (with $n_{k+1}>n_{k}$, and $n_k\rightarrow\infty$) converges to a finite limit as well, are both limits necessarily equal?

Comment: It is generally true that if $(a_n)$ converges to some real number, then every subsequences converges to the same real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You do not even need the sequence to be monotonic, and if $\{a_n\}$ converges then any subsequence will converge to the same limit.

Comment: Thanks so much! I went through a long proof and I needed this to be true.